# Deserialize dynamic objects from a json with C #

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have the following JSON:

```
{      
    "TimeSeries": {
        "2019-04-26": {
            "open": "20.9000",
            "high": "21.0000",
            "low": "20.7300",
            "close": "20.7300",
            "volume": "556200"
        },
        "2019-04-25": {
            "open": "20.8000",
            "high": "20.9100",
            "low": "20.6600",
            "close": "20.7800",
            "volume": "784200"
        }
    }
}
```

I Need Deserialize to a C# Object. The problem is the Column format, that represents the Date, is dynamic.

I've tried with Newtonsoft JSON, but to no avail. How do I turn this JSON into this object?

```
 public class PriceHistory
    {
        public decimal Open { get; set; }
        public decimal High { get; set; }
        public decimal Low { get; set; }
        public decimal Close { get; set; }
        public decimal Volume { get; set; }

        //THE PROBLEM IS THIS FIELD
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: How you Deserialize?

Comment: The question is precisely this, I do not know how to deserialize :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use these classes:

```
public class Root
{
    public Dictionary<DateTime, PriceHistory> TimeSeries { get; set; }
}

public class PriceHistory
{
    public decimal Open { get; set; }
    public decimal High { get; set; }
    public decimal Low { get; set; }
    public decimal Close { get; set; }
    public decimal Volume { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialization:

```
var json = File.ReadAllText("test.json");
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
```